# how to find out when the collection is updated?

Tags: mongodb

my simple question is how to find out when the collection is updated?
I have searched for and tried various ways to solve my problem, I have tried:

db.getCollection('examplecollection').stats()

db.getCollectionInfos({ name: "examplecollection" })

but between the two there is no information about when the collection was updated. can anyone help me?

best regards,

Comment: you can use mongo-change stream.

Comment: Have a look at [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer , let me read first.

Comment: I have tried to implement it at node.js according to the example. but instead an error. are there examples that I can learn?